# reload a div with updated data using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a link on my page that can be edited in place. When the input box is focused out I want to reload the parent li tag which has the id="<%=micropost.id%>"

```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#editing_yt_url_<%=micropost.id%>').focusout(function(){
          $('#<%=micropost.id%>').refresh();
          });
       });
  </script>
```

The `.refresh` part isn't working. `$('#<%=micropost.id%>').hide()` will hide the entire li tag so i know its responsive but I don't know the proper method to just refresh that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$("#<%=micropost.id%>").hide().fadeIn('fast');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPYUS/)

You have to approach the problem a bit differently. You are refreshing a widget, not a standard list. The framework wraps some additional elements around lists to turn them into the listviews. Make sure that you are calling the widget method on the resulting ul/ol instead of a wrapper.

Also, if you are loading the entire list with the .load call, you will need to initialize the widget, not refresh it. I think calling `$("#items_list").listview()` may be what you are after in that case.